# Joshcam PHP MySQLi Database Class SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using the Joshcam [MysqliDb](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php) to manage the database. I've successfully created a query to insert the data and i can query the database to fetch the results using this snippet that i've found in the documentation.

```
$cols = Array ("id", "name", "email");
$inviteMail = $db->get ("invitation", null, $cols);
if ($db->count > 0)
foreach ($inviteMail as $Mail) { 
    print_r ($Mail);
}
```

How i can verify if an user posted value is already present in the database table? With this query i can read all data of the table, and i don't wanna this, i'm reading the documentation on github (This is the first time i use this class) but for now i can't find a valid solution, so i try with this code i've written, but it give me the error that i've echoed also with different emails

```
$cols = Array ("id", "email", "token", "code");
$inviteMail = $db->get ("invitation", null, $cols);
if ($db->count > 0)
foreach ($inviteMail as $Mail) { 
    if($_POST[email] == $Mail){
echo 'email address already used.';
}
}
```

**EDIT**

I've modified the code using the suggested snippet but it give me an error. I've looked at the documentation and i've modified the code in this way..

```
$cols = Array ("email");
$inviteMail = 
$db->where('email', $_POST['invitation_email']);
$results = $db->get("invitation", null, $cols);
if ($results == $_POST['invitation_email']) {
echo 'email address already used.';
}
```

Now no error is logged but if i try with an already saved email address, the script don't check for the results. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cols = Array ("id", "email", "token", "code");
$inviteMail = $db
   ->where('email', $_POST['email'])
   ->get("invitation", null, $cols);

if ($db->count() > 0) {
   echo 'email address already used.';
}
```

**NB** I've started from this example code,but it give me an error **Call to a member function count()** . I've modified it and now i've this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$cols = Array ("username","password");
$db->where('username', $_POST['username']);
$db->where('password', $_POST['password']);
$login = $db->get('members', null, $cols);
if($login->count > 0){
        echo 'success';
        }
}
```

But i'm unable to verify if login details are correct. I have no idea of what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

imho the correct synatax would be.

```
if($db->where('email', $_POST['invitation_email'])->has('invitation')) {
    echo 'email address already used.';
}
```